# How to do geo distance sorting on realm data in ios objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

I am storing different location points in realm data. Now i want to sort realm data on the basis of the distance from particular latitude and longitude(or center point). Is there any method in realm to sort data or i have to calculate distance between two point and then distance use for sorting like below code.

```
RLMResults *getdata = [PersonDB allObjects];
CLLocation *locA = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:lat1 longitude:long1];

for (int i = 0; i < [getdata count]; i++) {
    PersonDB *person = [getdata objectAtIndex:i];
    CLLocation *locB = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude: person.
                        lat longitude: person.
                        long];
    CLLocationDistance distance = [locA distanceFromLocation:locB];

    RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];
    [realm beginWriteTransaction];
    person.distance = distance;
    [realm commitWriteTransaction];
}
RLMResults *realm_data = [PersonDB allObjects];
realm_data = [realm_data sortedResultsUsingProperty:@"distance" ascending:YES];
```

I found swift based library RealmGeoQueries which required radius and region. I don't want to define any boundaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, import module;

```
import GeoQueries
```

Search with MapView MKCoordinateRegion;

```
let results = try! Realm()
    .findInRegion(type: YourModelClass.self, region: mapView.region)
```

Search around the center with radius in meters;

```
let results = try! Realm()
    .findNearby(YourModeltype: Class.self, origin: mapView.centerCoordinate, radius: 500, sortAscending: nil)
```

Filter Realm results with radius in meters;

```
let results = try! Realm()
    .objects(YourModelClass.self)
    .filter("type", "restaurant")
    .filterGeoRadius(center: mapView.centerCoordinate, radius: 500, sortAscending: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Realm currently does not support geo-based operations, and so you'll have to either use a library or the code which you provided. It is something we [want to add in the future](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/2569#issuecomment-143271273), though -- if you want to see it please feel free to add a comment on that GitHub ticket!

Comment: Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the creator of [RealmGeoQueries](https://github.com/mhergon/RealmGeoQueries) and you can do this in Swift:

```
let results = Realm().objects(Point).sortByDistance(center: centerCoordinate, ascending: true)
```

You don't need anything else.

Comment: I will try this. Thank you.